# Storing a set of parameters in a dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsdictionary

I have a networking method that provides a friendly interface to my API. Something like:

```
    getWeatherForCities:(NSArray *)cityCodes 
              startDate:(NSDate *)startDate
                endDate:(NSDate *)endDate 
             useCelcius:(BOOL)useCelcius
             maxResults:(NSNumber *)maxResults
```

This is called multiple times in my app, sometimes concurrently with different parameters. There is also a completion and failure block but they aren't needed here.

I would like to add an option that tells the method only to execute the completion block if the data is different to the last time it was requested with the same parameters. This way some consumers can say that they want to know everything, and others can ask only for data if it is new.

It seems like I need some way to store a representation of all the parameters, alongside the last received response for those parameters. I would love to do this in an NSDictionary, but am open to other ideas. Is there some way to convert the parameters into a unique key? Or some better solution?

Comment: One more idea - could I create an NSDictionary from the parameters and use the `hash` method to generate a unique key from that dictionary? I am *kind-of* aware of `hash` and what it means for equality but is this a reasonable use?

Comment: Creating a string representation for each of the parameters and concatenating them into a single string and using that as your key is a good solution. The only problem i see with that is that if you have a huge dictionary you might save some memory with a hashing, but i wouldn't worry about this until profiling and measuring it to be a real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently using the `[dictionary description]` as the key.